# Make Keyboard Appear Automatically

Tags: java, codenameone

Is there a way to make the keyboard appear automatically on its own, without the user having to press the textfield first.

I noticed that if I use `textfield.pointerRelased(0, 0)` the keyboard shows up but its not functional.

Answer (score 1):

You can give your textfield a focus and fire keyboard open by doing this:

```
Display.getInstance().editString(textfield, textfield.getMaxSize(), TextArea.ANY, textfield.getText());
```

There is also some [newer way to do this](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/stackoverflow-cordova-update-validation-text-input-hints-icon.html) which are slightly simpler and should work with the next plugin update. For the common use case of editing a text field/area once a form is shown use:

```
myForm.setEditOnShow(textfield);
```

Just to launch editing use:

```
textField.startEditing();
```

Or better yet:

```
textField.startEditingAsync();
```

Which is equivalent to wrapping `startEditing` with a `callSerially`. That's generally a good practice to workaround some odd platform specific bugs.

Comment: Edited the answer with some additional options